# What is the usefulness of checking num_rows before while loop after SELECT query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop

In many scripts, programmers check if the `SELECT` query has returned any record before running the corresponding while loop as

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * From table WHERE column='XX'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ...
    }
}
```

Is this check necessary or useful at all? because when not returning any record, the while loop will not cycle. Can checking the number of returned rows improve the performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you usually do it for the case where no rows have returned, and you simply want to print out a nice message for the user. if you only have a while loop, you'll need to keep a counter and that can get ugly.

so it's there mainly for the

```
else {
  echo "No results found!";
}
```

;)

Comment: I understand the case you described, but in many cases, num_rows only cover the while loop without `else`; and this makes me wonder!

Comment: Right, but more in-line with the original question, if you do not intend to produce such a message is there any point to using the conditional prior to the while loop?

Comment: @ali. As you must know php is used by many coders only at amateur level. So many practices are common without good reasons.

Comment: When I develop database bound apps, I like to log all the possible outcomes of a query. so after a query, I usually first check for an error, then check that results returned, then start iterating. and return with a different return code and log message per each case. it just makes the code easier to understand and track (you can then grep your logs for all the queries that returned 0 results for example).

Comment: @user1169578 in my opinion, there is no need to do so. I asked this question to know if I'm missing a point, as others used this if condition. ;)

Comment: @NomikOS very interesting point! This has substantially affected the PHP standard coding :)

Comment: Well, if you've no need to take action with a zero row count I would not bother to make the check.  Whether or not it's a performance hit... probably, but most likely insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

To a programmer it's obvious that the code in the `WHILE` loop will not be executed if there are no rows returned. This is a common construct, so no further clarification is needed. Therefore, unless there is a branch, the `IF` is not required.

1. According to agile principles, we shouldn't put in code just because we might need it later.
2. We should simplify code whenever possible.

So, given two reasons not to put the redundant code in, I can't think of any reason to put it in there.

**GOOD:**

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * From table WHERE column='XX'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      ...
    }
} else {
  // Do something
}
```

**GOOD:**

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * From table WHERE column='XX'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ...
}
```

**BAD:**

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * From table WHERE column='XX'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You can even do `if(rows == 0) { printError(); } /*(else)*/ while(($row = fetch()) !== FALSE) { … }`